# Chef ssl validation failure

Tags: ssl, nginx, chef-infra, knife

I have one chef-server version 12.0.1 and can connect linux (rhel/centos) systems to the chef-server with knife bootstrap but cannot with windows and locally on my rhel client knife ssl check fails.

I have two problems but I think they are both related.

Problem 1 - knife ssl check fails:

```
Connecting to host chef-server:443
ERROR: The SSL certificate of chef-server could not be verified
```

Problem 2 - bootstrap windows server fails:

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: chef-server - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "desktop"
```

I have tried a number of things:
1) knife ssl fetch - no changes
2) I have a signed digicert crt on the server which is accepted by the management-console and chrome web browser
3) I have changed set this in the chef-server.rb

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/hostname.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/hostname.key"
```

which go to the signed certs.

Anything else I should be trying or am I being a plank?

Comment: I'm guessing you redacted the real hostnames, but make sure they all match. Even with trusted_certs, you still have to use the same hostname as the server generated the cert with.

Comment: Yes I did redact them. They are all identical :) I am also using a wildcard trusted cert if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, and we're using a wildcard certificate too. Possibly worth trying a single domain certificate? Had problems before where software refuses to match wildcard certificate to a subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these commands on your Chef server:

```
mkdir /root/.chef/trusted_certs    
cp /var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/YOUR_SERVER'S_HOSTNAME.crt /root/.chef/trusted_certs/
```

I was having the same problem and it was fixed after I looked through this article, and tried out the steps it gave:  http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using a valid wildcard certificate, although it was linux rather than windows.  Looks like the issue is that the chef client uses openssl and didn't have the CA and root certificates.  I was getting errors when I ran the following from the chef client server: 
`openssl s_client -connect chef_server_url*:443 -showcerts`

I solved my issue by browsing to the chef server, inspecting the certs and exporting each cert in the chain to a single file, ordered with the issued certificate at the top, and the root at the bottom. I then used this bundled-cert as the certificate file in the chef server config file and reconfigured chef.